# spawn in node not showing animation in terminal

Tags: node.js

When using `npm install marantz-avr` in a terminall you see a "process animation" in your terminal.

However when I execute `npm install` via:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

let npm = spawn('npm', ['install', 'marantz-avr', '--no-save']);

npm.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
});

npm.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

No animation is shown. In only shows the "normal text". Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` in the options seemed to do it, though I am curious why your code and/or piping onto the parent stdout/stderr doesn't work.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

```
let npm = spawn('npm', ['install', 'marantz-avr', '--no-save'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

You will also need to make sure the child process exits before the parent process exits:

```
function onExit () {
  npm.kill('SIGINT');
}
process.on('SIGINT', onExit);
process.on('SIGTERM', onExit);
process.on('exit', onExit);
```

Comment: Great find! Now ctrl+c doesn't kill the process anymore. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: Found it: I should use: `{ stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit'] }` instead

Comment: `stdio: 'inherit'` is just shorthand for `stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit']`. Though the child process should be told to exit first before the parent process exits. I updated my answer to show this.